# How to debug User Storage SPI plugin?

Tags: keycloak

I'm trying to build User Storage SPI, so I put the Jar file of the plugin in `/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/`, but it didn't appeared in User Federation page of Keycloak admin console, so I'm sure there are some errors, the problem is I don't know how to debug it, the keycloak docker container logs don't show logs about the status of the plugin other than `(DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010:Deployed <name>.jar" (runtime-name : "<name>.jar")`

Comment: Can you see the deployed provider from Admin panel > (Click username) Server info > providers tab.

Comment: I had to keep the jar file inside Downloads/keycloak-18.0.0/providers/ and then it started appearing on the User Federation screen. Once I selected it, restarted keycloak, and tried logging in, keycloak logs were giving me proper logs which helped me fix the issues related to the SPI.